# Javascript find location with lat,long and radius

Tags: javascript, geofence

I need to find all the locations near by the lat long and radius provided.I think I can achieve this by using geofence but I don't know how to proceed.I have the following data.
set of lat long and to get the location for radius within `5km` for all the lat long by each.

Any one help how to start this.

Inputs I have:

**lat long**

```
33.450909, -112.073196
33.466210, -112.064620
33.451640,  -112.099130
33.437160,  -112.048400
33.480860,  -112.082130
33.489950,  -112.074700
```

**Tried so far:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Creating a Store Locator on Google Maps</title>
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
     * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
 </style>
  </head>
  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initMap()">
    <div>
         <label for="raddressInput">Search location:</label>
         <input type="text" id="addressInput" size="15"/>
        <label for="radiusSelect">Radius:</label>
        <select id="radiusSelect" label="Radius">
          <option value="50" selected>50 kms</option>
          <option value="30">30 kms</option>
          <option value="20">20 kms</option>
          <option value="10">10 kms</option>
        </select>

        <input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search"/>
    </div>
    <div><select id="locationSelect" style="width: 10%; visibility: hidden"></select></div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 90%"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      var markers = [];
      var infoWindow;
      var locationSelect;

        function initMap() { 
          var sydney = {lat: 33.450909, lng: -112.073196};
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: sydney,
            zoom: 11,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
          });
          infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

          searchButton = document.getElementById("searchButton").onclick = searchLocations;

          locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
          locationSelect.onchange = function() {
            var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
            if (markerNum != "none"){
              google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
            }
          };
        }

       function searchLocations() {
         var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
         var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
         geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
           } else {
             alert(address + ' not found');
           }
         });
       }

       function clearLocations() {
         infoWindow.close();
         for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
           markers[i].setMap(null);
         }
         markers.length = 0;

         locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
         var option = document.createElement("option");
         option.value = "none";
         option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
         locationSelect.appendChild(option);
       }

       function searchLocationsNear(center) {
         clearLocations();

         var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
         var searchUrl = 'storelocator.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
         downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
           var xml = parseXml(data);
           var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
           var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
           for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
             var id = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("id");
             var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
             var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
             var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
             var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                  parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

             createOption(name, distance, i);
             createMarker(latlng, name, address);
             bounds.extend(latlng);
           }
           map.fitBounds(bounds);
           locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
           locationSelect.onchange = function() {
             var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
             google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
           };
         });
       }

       function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });
          markers.push(marker);
        }

       function createOption(name, distance, num) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = num;
          option.innerHTML = name;
          locationSelect.appendChild(option);
       }

       function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
          var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
              new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
              new XMLHttpRequest;

          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
              request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
              callback(request.responseText, request.status);
            }
          };

          request.open('GET', url, true);
          request.send(null);
       }

       function parseXml(str) {
          if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
            doc.loadXML(str);
            return doc;
          } else if (window.DOMParser) {
            return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
          }
       }

       function doNothing() {}
  </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAVD0ngfhOFs5rnww7UFyz9rN6UznOIZ1U&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using the above I can able to point single point,But what I want is to get the location around each lat long provided above radius is `5 km`

Comment: Please provide enough example and share some code where you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Google Maps, then I think you can try with computeDistanceBetween.

This is a short example of how to use it. You just need to eliminate those distances greater than the radius you set.

```
var home = ['Store', new google.maps.LatLng(29.520130, -98.415542)];

var pts = [
  ['Client A', new google.maps.LatLng(29.5197902, -98.3867079)],
  ['Client B', new google.maps.LatLng(29.5165967, -98.4235714)],
  ['Client C', new google.maps.LatLng(29.5198805, -98.3676648)]
];

var dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween;

pts.forEach(function(pt) {
  console.log(home[0] + ' to ' + pt[0] + ': ' + (dist(home[1], pt[1])).toFixed(10));
});
```